# Declare 2 standalone components in one UiBinder file?

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

I have a dialog which fires `ValidEvent` (GXT custom event) :

```
public class MyDialog extends Dialog implements HasValidHandlers {

  ...
}
```

So if I include it in a `UiBinder` file, I should be able to do something like (see @UiHandler) :

```
@UiField
MyDialog myDialog;

@UiHandler("myDialog")
void onValid(ValidEvent event) {
  ..
}
```

And I want to include the `MyDialog` in a widget also defined with `UiBinder` :

```
public class MyWidget extends Composite {

  @UiField
  MyDialog myDialog;

  public MyWidget(Binder binder) {
    initWidget(binder.createAndBindUi(this));
  }

  @UiHandler("myDialog")
  void onValid(ValidEvent event) {
    ..
  }

  interface Binder extends UiBinder<Widget, MyWidget> {}

}
```

**Problem :** Where to place the component in the `ui.xml` file?

Including the dialog in the component will causes graphical problem as UiBinder will try to add the Dialog IN the widget :

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
  <MyDialog ui:field="myDialog"/>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

**But** : In `uIBinder`, I can have only one root component.

**Question** : How can I declare 2 different components in a single `UiBinder` file? I would like to avoid making a `ui.xml` just to declare the Dialog and if I instantiate it via `new` the `@UiHandler` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You partly have answered your own question.

*Including the dialog in the component will causes graphical problem as UiBinder will try to add the Dialog IN the widget :*

Hence you will need to create a `ui-binder` separately for the component, as you also intend to use it as a `uiField` etc too!

According to my guess (based on my knowledge) each `ui-binder` creates a single widget and it can be referenced in another `ui-binder` or file as required.

Answer (score 0):

You can have [two UiBinder in the same widget](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Apply_different_xml) :

```
public class MyWidget extends Composite {

  MyDialog myDialog;

  public MyWidget(Binder binder) {
    initWidget(binder.createAndBindUi(this));
    DialogBinder dialogBinder = GWT.create(DialogBinder.class);
    myDialog = dialogBinder.createAndBindUi(this);
  }

  @UiHandler("myDialog")
  void onValid(ValidEvent event) {
    ..
  }

  interface Binder extends UiBinder<Widget, MyWidget> {}

  @UiTemplate("DialogBinder.ui.xml")
  interface DialogBinder extends UiBinder<MyDialog, MyWidget> {}

}
```

And your DialogBinder.ui.xml looks like :

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder">
    <MyDialog ui:field="myDialog"/>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

I don't test it, but there can be a problem with different @UiField.
You can doo this this an Inner Class who own all Dialog @UiField and @UiHander.